# Need to a compare the two array objects and create a new array of objects

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

Array structure

```
let array1 = [
  {
    '2023-08-03': { x: 179.159093242013, y: null },
    '2023-08-04': { x: 178.323000340271, y: 55.727942469807 },
    '2023-08-05': { x: null, y: 56.727774687963 },
    '2023-08-06': { x: 182.232246437691, y: 48.911777872434 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-08-08': { x: 180.147793830328, y: 57.752356407584 },
    '2023-08-09': { x: null, y: 47.714833999144 }
  }
] 
let array2 = [
  {
    '2023-07-03': { x: null, y: 45.2 },
    '2023-07-04': { x: 180.55307760927744, y: 48.4 },
    '2023-07-05': { x: 180.04640371229698, y: 55.8 },
    '2023-07-06': { x: 180.53989728172365, y: 57.4 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-07-08': { x: 168.59344894026975, y: 37.3 },
    '2023-07-09': { x: 178.7709497206704, y: 57.9 }
  }
]
```

I need to compare above two arrays and build a new one , but there are some condition like

1. if x value in array1 is null, then it should take the value from x in array2 on same date.
2. If y value in array1 is null, then it should take the value from y in array2 on same date.
3. If x & y values in  array1 is not null , then no need to take value from array2
   Like that I need to build a single array of objects

expected output should be like

```
let newArray = [{
    '2023-08-03': { x: 179.159093242013, y: 45.2 },
    '2023-08-04': { x: 178.323000340271, y: 55.727942469807 },
    '2023-08-05': { x: 180.04640371229698, y: 56.727774687963 },
    '2023-08-06': { x: 182.232246437691, y: 48.911777872434 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-08-08': { x: 180.147793830328, y: 57.752356407584 },
    '2023-08-09': { x: 178.7709497206704, y: 47.714833999144 }
}
]
```

Please help

I have tried many method, but nothing is working.

Comment: `array2` has mostly dates in July, whereas the first array has August, but it seems that in the result, the values from the `array2` are still taken. Why?

Comment: @wonderflame I'm interpreting this as array2 are the "fallback" or "default" values used to supply any missing (null) entries in array1.

Comment: @wonderflame Thats my mistake when copying object, the dates will be  same in both arrays. But there is one chance to miss any of the dates in array2 in some scenarios

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wka1jN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Hey that works, seems more fast !

Comment: should I post the answer?

Comment: Though I'm not sure if it is really faster than the answers that been already posted

Comment: @wonderflame You can post it , thanks

Comment: You have added wrong values in questions.Do u want 2nd array to be -07- dates or -08-dates?
i have added an answer based on ur question with different keys on both arrays.If u have clarification on what u need,Please  update your question .
@Vishnunarayananm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create a type for the array type:

```
type ArrType = Record<string, { x: number | null; y: number | null }>[];
```

Now, let's write a `merge` function that will accept two `ArrType` arguments and merge them into one.

To iterate over the array were are going to use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the accumulated value we a new array. Then, using the [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which will give us an array of tuples where the first element is the key and the second one is the value (`{x: type, y: type}`). Using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we are going to mutate the value in the entries to a new value using the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) according to the rules described in the OP. The last step is to convert the new tuples to an object, which can be done using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). Then, we will push the new object to the accumulated value:

```
const merge = (arr1: ArrType, arr2: ArrType) => {
  return arr1.reduce<ArrType>((acc, obj, index) => {
    acc.push(
      Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [
          key,
          {
            x: value.x ?? arr2[index][key]?.x ?? null,
            y: value.y ?? arr2[index][key]?.y ?? null,
          },
        ]),
      ),
    );

    return acc;
  }, []);
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ts=5.0.4#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-vLAB8GEhWGLKmrEFbXYbOYgAAo4Ug2OmYFnk4o4aRt5nswBKNAT-CEGDgNQwFTQOBIAQ30tqAsgcs7vcgCdrjcFgWihFu2ABWij1qWIAcOeqCXqiRBQIBAiJmolYABZrmUuAAPJgYWYACAAZjARatgAoioNa1iAlZYVEUR4aBBECCAVF1rRa4gaBp4CK2UCJv+GAANYgAgigAG5QMAaggGCsGXtgDEMaJ4nYQxCHKVElhSTJIACBwEAAPxGY+MCkBgkHQWCIliWCRkGcZpnYupykeLpskCAgTlmRZVkcDZqn2V5PkuVpRD4sp8kslEp4xRAp5xlEN5gHeD5IQWUKgoo06JVg2hxnOlZFqAAjAEWDZrkuMArhucCIF0cKIKQp55UAA)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Note the try catch block that prevents the code from crashing if a date is not in array2

Assuming both arrays have the same number of objects, this should work for you:

```js
let array1 = [
    {
      '2023-08-03': { x: 179.159093242013, y: null },
      '2023-08-04': { x: 178.323000340271, y: 55.727942469807 },
      '2023-08-05': { x: null, y: 56.727774687963 },
      '2023-08-06': { x: 182.232246437691, y: 48.911777872434 },
      '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
      '2023-08-08': { x: 180.147793830328, y: 57.752356407584 },
      '2023-08-09': { x: null, y: 47.714833999144 }
    }
  ] 
  let array2 = [
    {
      '2023-08-03': { x: null, y: 45.2 },
      '2023-08-04': { x: 180.55307760927744, y: 48.4 },
      '2023-08-05': { x: 180.04640371229698, y: 55.8 },
      '2023-08-06': { x: 180.53989728172365, y: 57.4},
      '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
      '2023-08-08': { x: 168.59344894026975, y: 37.3 },
    //   '2023-08-09': { x: 178.7709497206704, y: 57.9 }
    }
  ]

  const makeNewArr = (arr1, arr2) => {
    // error
    if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return [];
      
    newArr = [];
      
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        
        obj1 = arr1[i];
        obj2 = arr2[i];
        
        for (const key in obj1) {
            for (const prop in obj1[key]) {
                // try catch in case obj2 does not have the fields obj1 has
                try {
                    if (obj1[key][prop] === null && obj2[key][prop] !== null) obj1[key][prop] = obj2[key][prop]; 
                } catch {}
            }
        }
        newArr.push(obj1);
    }
    return newArr;
  }

  console.log(makeNewArr(array1, array2));
```

output:

```js
[
  {
    '2023-08-03': { x: 179.159093242013, y: 45.2 },
    '2023-08-04': { x: 178.323000340271, y: 55.727942469807 },
    '2023-08-05': { x: 180.04640371229698, y: 56.727774687963 },
    '2023-08-06': { x: 182.232246437691, y: 48.911777872434 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-08-08': { x: 180.147793830328, y: 57.752356407584 },
    '2023-08-09': { x: null, y: 47.714833999144 }
  }
]
```

Comment: For sure! Please see and use the updated code, I added a try catch incase a date is not present in array2 but is present in array1

Answer (score 0):

below is a full javscript code for your particular use case.

```
let array1 = [
  {
    '2023-08-03': { x: 179.159093242013, y: null },
    '2023-08-04': { x: 178.323000340271, y: 55.727942469807 },
    '2023-08-05': { x: null, y: 56.727774687963 },
    '2023-08-06': { x: 182.232246437691, y: 48.911777872434 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-08-08': { x: 180.147793830328, y: 57.752356407584 },
    '2023-08-09': { x: null, y: 47.714833999144 }
  }
] 
let array2 = [
  {
    '2023-07-03': { x: null, y: 45.2 },
    '2023-07-04': { x: 180.55307760927744, y: 48.4 },
    '2023-07-05': { x: 180.04640371229698, y: 55.8 },
    '2023-07-06': { x: 180.53989728172365, y: 57.4 },
    '2023-08-07': { x: null, y: null },
    '2023-07-08': { x: 168.59344894026975, y: 37.3 },
    '2023-07-09': { x: 178.7709497206704, y: 57.9 }
  }
]
let array3=[...array1];
const aobj1=array1[0];
const aobj2=array2[0];
const aobj3=array3[0];
function editstring(str){
    return str.replace(/-08-/g, "-07-");
}
for (key in aobj1) {
    let newobjtopush={};xval=aobj1[key]['x'];yval=aobj1[key]['y'];
    let secondkey=editstring(key);
    if(aobj2[secondkey]){
      if(!aobj1[key]['x']) {
       xval=aobj2[secondkey]['x']?aobj2[secondkey]&&aobj2[secondkey]['x']:null;
       }
      if(!aobj1[key]['y']) {
       yval=aobj2[secondkey]['y']?aobj2[secondkey]&&aobj2[secondkey]['y']:null;
       }
    }
    aobj3[key]['x']=xval;
    aobj3[key]['y']=yval;
}
console.log(array3) //here is your desired output
```